# Determine Which Layout Application is Currently Using

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have 2 Fragments and a Main Activity. An Item from a List in Fragment A is Clicked, the id is retrieved in the Main Activity and the 2nd Fragment replaces the First. This happens in the following interface method within Main Activity:

```
    @Override
public void onCLicked(int id) {
   //Launch Fragment B/Pass id to it
}
```

That works well on a phone screen.

I now made a 2nd layout for a Tablet where the Fragments are side by side. My new layout is in my resource layout-sw720-land folder and looks like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:context="com.markf.popularmovies.activities.MainActivity"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerDetail"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:context="com.markf.popularmovies.activities.MainActivity"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/container"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
</FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This layout launches when I'm using my tablet but when I click on an item, Fragment A is replaced with Fragment B as if it was still on the phone. Is there a way to do determine which layout Im in programmatically so I could code this appropriately? I tried reading this solution:[Android Developer:Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

but no luck

Comment: Assuming the `FrameLayout` with ID `containerDetail` is not in the phone layout, if `findViewById(R.id.containerDetail)` returns null, then you're in the phone layout.

Comment: Makes sense. That works. You can answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to check for the existence of a `View` that's unique to one of the layouts. In this case, since the `FrameLayout` with ID `containerDetail` is only in the tablet layout, if `findViewById(R.id.containerDetail)` returns null, then you're in the phone layout.

For example:

```
if (findViewById(R.id.containerDetail) == null) {
    // Phone layout
}
else {
    // Tablet layout
}
```